# C# : HttpListener I/O operation aborted

Tags: c#, multithreading, http, range, iostream

I'm trying to integrate range functionality into my HttpServer, but I keep on getting this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.HttpListenerException'
>   occurred in System.dll
>
> Additional information: The I/O operation has been aborted because of
>   either a thread exit or an application request

I'd like to mention that my HttpListener is running on a Thread, and I'm using BeginGetContext.

Any idea whats causing this error?

```
if (File.Exists(RequestedFile))
{
    Stream ReadStream = new FileStream(RequestedFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

    //Get Range
    try
    {
         string[] RangeArray = HttpRequest.Headers.GetValues("Range")[0].Replace("bytes=", "").Split('-');
         long.TryParse(RangeArray[0], out StartChunk);
         if (RangeArray[1].Trim().Length > 0)
         {
             long.TryParse(RangeArray[1], out EndChunk);
         }
         if (EndChunk == 0) { EndChunk = (int)ReadStream.Length; }
         ChunkRange = EndChunk - StartChunk;
    }
    catch
    {
         StartChunk = 0;
         EndChunk = ReadStream.Length;
         ChunkRange = EndChunk - StartChunk;
    }

    HttpResponse.ContentType = "video/mp4";
    HttpResponse.ContentLength64 = ChunkRange;

    //Start File Processing
    byte[] Buffer = new byte[ChunkRange];
    ReadStream.Position = StartChunk;
    ReadStream.Read(Buffer, 0, (int)ChunkRange);
    ReadStream.Flush();
    ReadStream.Close();

    //Flush to Response
    HttpResponse.OutputStream.Write(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length);//error occurs here

    HttpResponse.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
    HttpResponse.OutputStream.Flush();

}
else { HttpResponse.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound; }

HttpResponse.OutputStream.Close();
```

**UPDATE**
It appears that this occurs due Chrome. [Read accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549226/c-httplistener-error-serving-content)

Comment: You are only allocating ChunkRange to buffer, but then reading Buffer.Length.  What happens if Buffer.Length > ChunkRange?

Comment: I changed both to ChunkRange and Buffer.Lenght. Still get an error when writing to output stream.

Comment: The connection must  be closed.  Usually debug errors like this using a sniffer (fiddler or wireshark).